# I need help understanding Titanium Alloy (MVC) development

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm used to developing in MVC frameworks such as cake and backbone, but I can't get my head around developing in Alloy.  There don't seem to be any good examples online.  I would be very grateful if someone could give an example of how you would set up a couple buttons that respond to click events and bring you to new windows.  I'm also using Ti's map api to show a google map, but I'm not sure how to correctly initialize that either.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

here are very helpful links for MVC Alloy

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/143969/alloy-mvc-examples

Answer (score 2):

Here are my collection of helpful links that I use often:

Alloy Quick Start

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Quick_Start

Alloy Framework Guides

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework

Alloy Google Group for high-level discussion only (no Q&A)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/appc-ti-alloy

Alloy github repository

https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy

Alloy test apps, kinda like individual Kitchen-Sink-esque app

https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/test/apps

Alloy XML View
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_XML_Markup

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Samples-section-37535160_AlloySamples-TestCaseExamples

RSS reader example
https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/samples/rss

Answer (score 1):

Here is very helpful [links for MVC Alloy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0adAsLE0v4)